# Save your Justice Ready! for the right monster

Tags: pc, deathspank

If I understood well it seems that when your *justice-meter* is filled up you consume it as soon as you use any *violet* weapons.

If you equip DeathSpank with two violet weapons you have then no choice to keep Justice for the right moment. If you instead equip him with 1 violet and 1 non-violet weapon you cannot build up combo multiplier using your weapons alternatively.

Is really designed in that way or am I miss something? Is it possible having more control on your **Justice Ready!** and decide when really use it?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually have 4 weapons installed, one for each face button (A, B, X, Y on the 360). What I did is equip a ranged weapon to B, a violet weapon to Y, and normal weapons to A and X. I would typically attack by alternating A and X, and only use Y when the Justice meter was full and I needed a more powerful attack.

This way you can build your combo, but not waste the Justice meter until you need it.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I am playing with PC version. In PC version you have 2 sets of weapons that you can change using TAB. I will try to see if I can reconfigure it so that I can assign a different weapon to 4 different keys.

Comment: @Drake Maybe make one set your normal weapons (what I used with A and X), and the other containing the violet weapon and ranged weapon.